# Bootstrap and react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, react-bootstrap

I am learning react.js and I need to make my app responsive. What should I use? Bootstrap or react-bootstrap? Can I use Bootstrap in react? Or I need to use react-bootstrap? What's the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) is a UI library of components similar to [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) or a lot other UI libraries, while Bootstrap alone is a collection of CSS classes + HTML UI components.

You are free to choose between them, react-bootstrap or Bootstrap by your choice.

You can read more about them [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Bootstrap-and-React-Bootstrap)

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap:

```
import * as React from 'react';

function Example()  {
  return (
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Oh snap! You got an error!</strong> 
      <p> 
        Change this and that and try again.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

React-Bootstrap:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
function Example() {
  return (
    <Alert dismissible variant="danger">
      <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
      <p>
        Change this and that and try again.
      </p>
    </Alert>
  )
}
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.